# convert query() to find() cakephp

Tags: cakephp, find, case

```
    $v = array(1,11.38,15.8);
    $sortByPrice = $this->Product->query
    (
    "SELECT *,
    CASE `currency` 
        WHEN '1' THEN $v[0]
        WHEN '2' THEN $v[1]
        WHEN '3' THEN $v[2]
    END AS 'ratio'
    FROM products
    ORDER BY price*ratio DESC
    "
    );
```

i want to convert what is above to a find function
i tried something like that(but it do not work)..

```
    $v = array(1,11.38,15.8);
    $bla = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'Product.currency',
    '((
        CASE WHEN 
            Product.currency=1 THEN $v[0]
            Product.currency=2 THEN $v[1]
            Product.currency=3 THEN $v[2]
        END
    )) AS ratio'),
    'order' => 'ratio',
     'limit' => 10
     ));
```

can somebody to convert query into find

Comment: can I ask why you need to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting into the `conditions` key. Move it into the `fields` key or make it a `virtualField` - that *may* work.

Edit: also `$v[0]` in single quotes will not actually replace it with the variable - it will just appear as that text.